# Restore 1 site collection from a content database that contains several other site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, site-collection, content-database

for testing purposes I need to restore a site collection form our Live environment to our test farm environment. I have done this a few times where a site collection has its own database, but in this occasion, the content database in question contains several other site collections that do not require restore.

Is there a way to only restore the content of 1 site collection?

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it couple of ways.

Backup and restore Site collection

- Backup the site collection in question ( [backup-spsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx))
- move the backup to test farm
- restore the site using [restore-spsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx).

Move site into own content DB

- create a new content db
- use [move-spsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915.aspx) to move the site collection into the new content db
- now use Database baackup or restore method.

[Restore Unattached Content DB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269601(v=office.14).aspx)

- restore the content db in test farm.
- then just take the backup of site collection in question, using the central admin Unattached Content DB restore.
- restore that backup.

lastly, you can restore the content DB then delete all the unwanted site collections.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [`SharePoint Unattended Content Database Restore`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269602.aspx) method. The TechNet article linked provides the exact steps that you need to follow.